# Can you exactly tell the contents of the JDK in the computer?

Tags: java, jvm

Now don't just downvote or flag this question based on the title. I know the hierarchy of the JDK, JRE and JVM, but only in theory. I don't know where it is located exactly on the computer. I have installed JDK on my computer and it looks like this.[image]

My question is what do these folders `bin`, `conf`, `include`, `jmods`, `legal` and `lib` contain? Where is the JRE and JVM? Where are the Development tools and the remaining files of the JRE except the JVM? And is this the same in Linux and macOS?

Comment: where "it" is, you can have several jdk's and jre's installed.

Comment: That sounds like a [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/600226)-Question for what do you want to know this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installed-directory-structure-jdk-and-jre.htm#JSJIG-GUID-F7178F2F-DC92-47E9-8062-CA6B2612D350

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at a Java 9+ distribution there, and that is what this Answer is about.

> My question is what do these folders bin, conf, include, jmods, legal and lib contain?

- The `bin` directory contains the executable files for the tools.
- The `conf` directory contains various configuration files.
- The `include` directory contains C / C++ include files (for people who need to compile native code libraries against the JDK).
- The `jmods` directory contains the (Java 9+) modules that comprise the standard class libraries and the Java tools.
- The `legal` directory contains legal documents; e.g. license documents.
- The `lib` directory contains native code libraries that are part of the codebase.

> Where is the JRE and JVM?

The "JRE" is the name of a kind of distribution that no longer exists.  It is no longer relevant.  Oracle stopped distributing a distinct JRE distribution starting with Java 9.  The (formerly) JRE tools are in the `bin` directory, along with native libraries, modules and so on.

The "JVM" is an abstraction that exists *while you are running a Java program*.  To the extent that it is a tangible thing, you could (at a stretch) say that it comprises the `bin/java` executable together with  native libraries, and so on.

> Where are the Development tools and the remaining files of the JRE except the JVM?

In the `bin` directory, the `jmod` directory and so on.

They are not segregated from the tools that were formerly part of the JRE.
Each of the development tools is a Java application that *runs* a JVM, so *that* distinction is not meaningful.

> And is this the same in Linux and MacOS?

Yes, though there might be minor differences in the directory structure.

(In the case of Linux, it may depend on how the people who create your Linux distro have decided to organize the packages.)